# Interesting maxmin mixed integer/real quadratic optimization problem

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I have the following problem:

$
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}
\argmax_{\underset{\lambda_k\in \mathbb{R}}{\sigma_q^2(k)\in \mathbb{R}}} 
\left[\min_{\underset{q\in \left[q_A,q_B\right]}{n_k\in \mathbb{Z}}}
\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{\sigma_q^2(k)}\left(q-n_k\lambda_k\right)^2
\right] \qquad \mbox{s.t.}\qquad \sum_{k=1}^N  \frac{1}{\sigma_q(k)}=S
$

where the function to be minimized is quadratic both in the continuous variable $q$ and in the integer variables $n_k$ however I am having some problems translating it into a standard form. I tried to use the properties of the Hadamard product but that did not help much. Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any constraints? If not, why not take $\sigma^2_q(k)$ to be (arbitrarily close to) zero, driving overall max objective to $\infty$, i.e., unbounded, i.e., not a very interesting problem.

Comment: Good catch, there was indeed a missing constraint that I just added.

Comment: @Arrigo Are the $\sigma_q(k)$ just notation or is  $\sigma_q(k)$ some kind of function evaluated at the $k$'s? Is there any relationship among the different $\lambda_k$'s or are they independent?